# iOS Background fetch mode

Tags: ios, background, fetch, long-running-processes

What about the iOS "background fetch" mode? Apple documentation seems to be quite generic here:
*"...At appropriate times, the system gives background execution time to the apps..."
"...Only apps that provide important services to the user are allowed..."*

1. Is there a time threshold (explicitly specified or empirical) within which the system passes control to the app in the background? (I could tolerate a 5-min interval)
2. Does anyone can apply for "background fetch" permission?

NOTE:
The requirement is to to make remote calls at certain times (eg, 10.30AM 15:15 PM, ...) and show the result in a notification (all without the use of server-side push notifications). Since it is practically [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227882/local-notification-custom-code) to bind some custom code to a pre-scheduled local notification, I was wondering if it was possible to exploit a "background fetch" mode long running task to make the call only at necessary times.

Answer (score 0):

I have used background fetch with Push notification. Like when push notification will arrived, Application will start downloading new data with background fetch. It gives 30 sec. time to do our download or upload task once we start background fetch.

I think in your case you will able to use it at regular interval but not sure if you can register local notification from it and show it to user when app is in background.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if i can do it without push notification (and a server infrastructure backend). If via background fetch i'll not be able to register local notifications, then this is a problem. Another problem is how often the OS will give control to my task, to be sure of being able to comply with a tolerance of at least 5 minutes.

Comment: any suggestions here?

Comment: You can register local notification with background fetch but we can not be sure about time interval after which back ground fetch method will call by iOS. It might be called after 5 or after 20 minutes sometimes.

Comment: Do you know what the maximum interval is? It is a big difference, if the maximum interval is 15 or 60 minutes for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple's Background Fetch mode does not give any control over the intervals when fetch is done.

See also:
[iOS background fetch custom interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381083/ios-background-fetch-custom-interval),
[iOS background fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877335/ios-background-fetch)