# IOS - Background receive notification

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm looking at a way to receive (any form of) a notification in IOS (iPhone). 
This is needed for a "nurse call" like project and should work regardless of internet connection.

But there are a few "small" restrictions.

- It must work on a local network (no connection to the world wide web).
- The app must work in background (not always opened).
- The response time should be 1 minute max.

If it's of any help, I do have the possibility of using a local Apple MacOSX server.

---

**Things I've tried.**

I've looked at Apple Push Notifications, though I believe it will need access to the APNs (server). And can't work locally.

I've looked at keeping an "server" open in an IOS app, though this server will certainly be killed when the app is not in the foreground.

I've looked at the background mode "fetch", but it's not possible to set the frequency and it [may just work once every 30 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381083/ios-background-fetch-custom-interval).

I've looked at the Apple server, but I'd rather not use a local e-mail server since it's probably not fast enough and it'll not be possible to interact with an app this way.

The "Messages Server" seems to be interesting, but I'm not sure if I can receive those messages on an iPhone (from a local server, withouth the need of Apple servers).

Comment: There are no additional options. See: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40587060/1457385).

Comment: Without an internet connection PuchNotifications will not work since they require an active connection to the push notification servers of Apple.

Comment: @shallowThought what about the "Messages Server" or is it completely unrelated to this (and probably also requires internet)?

Comment: There is no way to host your own "message server", your best option is to use VOIP, as VOIP apps can keep a socket open to listen to incoming calls.

Comment: @ rckoenes: you are right. I missed that point. BackgroundFetch is the only chance.

Comment: BackgroundFetch is very unreliable, since iOS will determen if you and when you are allowed to fetch. Thus if something is draining the phone battery all background fetched are stopped. Also the user can turn this off very easily. VOIP might be the best way to go, but you will need to built real VOIP functionality in your app if you are going to release it in the app store

Comment: What about the "Apple messages server"? At this point, only a local email server has a chance of getting the iPhone to go "pling", or does this also need an active world wide web connection?

Comment: @rckoenes will VOIP work locally? Without connection to the apple servers (or only connection to a local MacOSX server)?